# How to scrape and extract similar xpaths onto different rows in csv using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm faced with a page which consists of multiple H2 tags and I require all those titles to be stored on separate rows in my csv sheet. I'm using scrapy for this and my current code is :

```
item ["title"] = titles.select("//h2/text()").extract()
```

Obviously, this ends up storing all the h2 tags of that page into one single cell in my csv.

Is there any way by which I can have a break after it scrapes each h2 tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on each `h2` and create an Item per `h2`, setting the "title" for each:

```
    items = []
    for title in titles.select("h2"):

        item = MyItem()

        # note the relative XPath expression (starting with "./")
        item["title"] = title.select("./text()").extract()

        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Comment: Is there any way I can loop on a Div[Class] ? 

Also, it gives me the following warning "call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead"

Comment: With newer Scrapy versions, you can use XPath with `.xpath()` instead of `.select()`, and for `div`s with a specific class you would write `.xpath('.//div[@class="something"]')`. You can also you CSS selectors, that are sometimes easier to write, read and maintain: `.css('div.something')`

Comment: I can't seem to make this statement work :
for titles in titles.xpath(".//div[class='page-header']"):

Comment: You're missing an `@` sign in the predicate (condition): `for title in titles.xpath(".//div[@class='page-header']")` (and use `for title in ...` instead of `for titles in ...`

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for that. 
It still stores all the data in a single cell:

def parse(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)  
   titles = hxs.select("//html")
   items = []
   
   for titles in titles.select("//div[@class='page-header']"):
     item = Item()
     item ["product"] = titles.select("//h2/text()").extract()
     items.append(item)

Comment: Use relative XPath expressions, i.e. starting with `./` and not `//`: `for div in hxs.xpath(".//div[@class='page-header']"): ... item["product"] = div.xpath(".//h2/text()")`